# Why my program is not returning the correct string value

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to write a program that asks the user to enter two points. Each point is entered one at a time. Then I need the x coordinate to me less than or equal to 5 and greater than or equal to -5.

I need to follow the same logic but with 2.5 and -2.5. For some reason it's not returning the string statement after the check. I don't have any syntax errors, so I am not sure what the issue is.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class coordinates {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //prompt user to enter coordinates 
        System.out.println("Enter a X coordinate: ");
        double x = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter a Y coordinate: ");
        double y = input.nextDouble();

        //check x coordinate to see if it is less or equal to 5 and greater than or equal to -5 
        if (x <= 5 && x >= -5){
            if (y <= 2.5 && y >= -2.5)
                System.out.println("Yes"); 
        }else
            System.out.println("no");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a hint - always use `{ }` characters with `if/else` statements; otherwise it can get very confusing figuring out what the scope of each `if` is.  Not doing this is a huge source of errors.

Comment: OKay, I another question how do you print this out: Point(x,y) is in the range.

Answer (score 0):

If your `x` value is in range but your `y` value is not in range, then nothing will be printed, because the first `if` was followed but the second `if` was not followed.  Change your `if` condition to one bigger condition, so that if either condition fails, then the `else` will be followed.

```
if ((x <= 5 && x >= -5) && (y <= 2.5 && y >= -2.5)) {
    System.out.println("Yes");
}else {
    System.out.println("no");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have one more question, how do I form my print out line if I want it to say: Point(x,y) is in the range

Comment: @user3240208 just make it: `System.out.println("Point(" + x + ", " + y + ") is in the range");` instead of the "Yes" text. That's called concatenation (if you want to Google it for more information and how it works).